# Qt: Automatic generation of power point report or editable pdf report

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, powerpoint

I am looking how to generate editable reports with Qt. Like a PowerPoint presentation with pictures, editable tables, and texts.

My first idea was creating a macro in PowerPoint. Then I think to use the library "QPdf" but it's not editable. Or Qfile and code a latex (beamer) presentation, but guys on my team don't want to use latex. Furthermore they already have a macro they are not convinced...

So I have to find another way, and directly use Qt...
I think to create a code text (with Qfile or QTextStream) for an html page, but I have to convert in PDF or PowerPoint after.

That's why I am asking you, is there an easy way to code an Editable presentation/report with Qt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a PDF directly with Qt using QPrinter class http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html

indicating the output format with

```
setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat)
```